How can I migrate users from Clerk development instance to production instance?
I created a web app with Next.js which uses clerk for authentication. I deployed the app and shared it with people and quickly reached clerk's user limit for development instances (100). I bought a domain and created a production instance. Everything works fine but I have no idea how to migrate the users from the deployment instance to the production instance. I tried following this guide but it does not work. When I tried to submit it in valid schema, I get this message in the logs
{
  "userId": "1",   
  "status": 422,
  "clerkTraceId": "b7bcb8a0a114ae7bda61de95ea5a92f1",
  "clerkError": true,
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "form_param_unknown",
      "message": "is unknown",
      "meta": {}
    }
  ],
  "originalLine": 155,
  "originalColumn": 12
}

The migration script doesn't even work with the sample JSON they provided. Same error.
I tried following the guide but it still does not work. I checked that all the credentials and env vars are correct so I really don't know how to migrate the users. I found a similar question in which the error code was different but one of the answers linked to a discord channel (which does not exist) so I'm still stuck.
